# TimeOut Error while obtaining SSL certificate from Lets Encrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lets-encrypt, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am following [rails acme-client](https://github.com/unixcharles/acme-client#setting-up-a-client) to automate the task of obtaining certificates

**Code for making CSR request**

```
new_private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(4096)
csr = Acme::Client::CertificateRequest.new(private_key: new_private_key, subject: { common_name: '4a58d2f2.ngrok.io' })
order.finalize(csr: csr)
sleep(5) while order.status == 'processing'
puts "certificate ordered=#{order.certificate}"
```

I am successfully able to complete **http challenge** as challenge.status returns valid

I am getting error **Acme::Client::Error::Timeout** at the last line

```
puts "certificate ordered=#{order.certificate}"
```

infact **order.status** is **valid**. Really strange!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [Last FAQ on the official website of lets encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/#i-successfully-renewed-a-certificate-but-validation-didn-t-happen-this-time-how-is-that-possible)

I hosted the rails app on Heroku and its all fixed.

Error could also be because I was trying to obtain certificate for url of **ngrok.io**